# Exotic smooth structures on Calabi-Yau manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

A Calabi-Yau manifold is a simply-connected closed Kähler manifold with holomorphically trivial canonical bundle and $h^{2, 0}=0$.

If two Calabi-Yau manifolds are homeomorphic are they diffeomorphic?